# Couldn't find Subscriber with 'id'= - Rails Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

Currently I have a `Subscriber` model and `Comments` model that belongs to `Subscriber`. Right now I need to link two models together so that my `Subscriber` has many `comments` on it. what I want is so that if I write this in the console I'll get my answer -> `Subscriber.find(1).comments.first` right now that returns nil because it doesn't know how to find the id of the subscriber that is leaving the comment. How can I give the application the proper code so that I can link the two? I'll post code for clarity.

CONTROLLER:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @comment = Comment.new
  end

  def create
    @subscriber = Subscriber.find(params[:subscriber_id])
    @comment = @subscriber.comments.build(comments_params)
    if @comment.save
      flash[:notice] = "Thank you!"
      redirect_to subscribers_search_path(:comments)
    else
      render "new"
    end
   end

  private

  def comments_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:fav_drink, :subscriber_id)
  end
end
```

As you can see I'm trying to find the :subscriber_id when I create the comment. That is where my problem is. How can I connect it

ERROR:

[image]

MODELS:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :subscriber 
end


class Subscriber < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end
```

Another aspect I should be clear about is that I have no current subscriber because this app is used for checking in a customer so the app does not log the user in it just checks them in with their phone number. Let me know if you need more info.

VIEWS:

```
 <h1>new</h1>

<%= form_for @comment do |form| %>
 <div class="form-group">
 <p>
  <%= form.label :fav_drink %>
  <%= form.text_field :fav_drink %>
  <%= form.hidden_field :subscriber_id %>
 </p>
  <%= form.submit "Send", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
 </div>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: Based on the error message on the page, I think you have a `nil` value for `params[:subscriber_id]`.

Could you show me the erb file? Also, you could debug yourself what's in the `params`.

Comment: yeah, I would assume that you might be looking for `params[:id]` depending how your routes are. So at the moment as Larry Lv pointed out you might have a `nil` value

Comment: @LarryLv I add the erb file Thank you

Comment: Where are you setting this? "  <%= form.hidden_field :subscriber_id %>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1**

You subscriber id is inside the `comment` hash in your params. So you need to find subscriber like this

```
@subscriber = Subscriber.find(params[:comment][:subscriber_id])
#If you're taking this approach, you need to remove :subscriber id from your comment_params
```

Lik this

```
def comment_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:fav_drink)
end
#@subscriber.comments.build will take care of the subscriber_id field for you, so its pointless rewriting it
```

**Method 2**

Or you directly create your comment.

```
@comment = Comments.new(comments_params)
#notice this already has, the subscriber_id, so we don't need to find
#subscriber and then do build on it
```

Let me know if that helps

Comment: Thanks. This helps it's just that I think I'm having trouble describing my problem. If I use method 2 It won't link that comment to the Subscriber, you know what I mean? The problem I think is that there is no "current_user". I'll say it this way I know what the error is saying in my question I just don't know how to fix it

Comment: Okay, so according to your form erb, `subscriber_id` is not being passed in params. So yeah, method 2 won't work in your particular case. Let me give you another suggestion.